# Конвертирование файлов

Tags: php

Задача: вводим имя файла, формат в который надо конвертировать и куда сохранить конвертируемый файл.Входные файлы могут быть `CSV,Xml и Json`. Написал до момента, когда надо достать из файла информацию, записывать в переменную, конвертировать в другой формат и записывать в файл. Как это собственно совершить? Именно функции перевода из формата в формат интересуют, можно ли выполнить с помощью PHP? `SplFileObject` желательно использовать. В документации нашёл только чтение из CSV с помощью `fgetcsv()`.

Comment: для json использовать json_decode, для xml в гугле наберите "php xml". ну а из файла сами читайте что бы текстом в эти функции передавать. Функций перевода форматов не существует, потому что они не могут быть универсальными, это только ручками, поэлементно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, PHP не предоставляет подобных способов перевода форматов "из коробки".

Я немного не понял, откуда именно у вас берётся файл - его загружает пользователь или он уже существует? Необходимо ли отдавать файл обратно или достаточно сохранить его на сервере? Дополните, пожалуйста, этот момент.

Работа с файлами в PHP довольно проста, я покажу вам несколько переводов в другой формат, чтобы вы уловили суть.

**CSV в JSON:**

```
$csvFile = fopen('path-to-csv-file', 'r');
$jsonFile = fopen('path-to-new-json-file', 'w+');

foreach($data = fgetcsv($csvFile) !== null) {
    fwrite($jsonFile, json_encode($data));
}

fclose($csvFile);
fclose($jsonFile);
```

Немного пояснений: здесь мы читаем каждую строку csv файла, при помощи функции fgetcsv(). Если у вас в CSV заданы отличные от стандартных символы перевода строки или колонки, в эту функцию эти символы можно передать. Далее мы будем записывать в json файл считанные данные до тех пор, пока fgetcsv() не вернёт null - что означает окончание файла (или ошибку). При желании исходный csv можно удалить.

**JSON в CSV:**

```
$jsonFile = fopen('path-to-json-file', 'r');
$csvFile = fopen('path-to-new-csv', 'w+');

// Оператор true читает данные как массивы, а не объект.
$data = json_decode($jsonFile, true) 
foreach ($data as $row) {
    fwrite($csvFile, $row);
}

fclose($jsonFile);
fclose($csvFile);
```

Форматирование данных из JSON немного сложнее - здесь необходимо видеть и знать саму структуру данных. Я показал лишь базовый пример.

Для более подробной помощи мне необходимо знать формат ваших данных.

Answer (score 1):

Например, работа с json. По той же аналогии работайте с остальными. Ищите нужные функции на официальном сайте в документации.

```
$file = "test.txt";
$test_data = array(
    'ttt' => '565t',
    'dfdf' => 'dfgt55',
    'ваа' => array(
        'ddf' => 5, 
    ),
    //другие данные
);
$fle = fopen($file, 'w+');
fwrite($fle, json_encode($test_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)); //преобразуем в json представление
fclose($fle);

//json to array
$array=json_decode($json_data_from_file);
```